# When I build out my Unity project, it breaks the reference to my alembic (.abc) file and I don't know how to fix it?

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I have an alembic file in Assets/Blender in my Unity project. I have an object which references the files in here for an animation.

If I run the game in Editor mode, everything is fine. When I build the game I have an issue though.I get this error:

File does not exist: D:/Unity/3D/Builds/BulletHell/BulletHell_Data/StreamingAssets\Assets/Blender/PerfectSphere.abc

I checked my StreamingAssets folder and I see an .abc file there but it's got a hashed name. There is no Assets/Blender/ folder.

How do I fix this so it works both in editor mode and once I build the game?

Just to provide some additional context as well:

1. In the actual project, the files are stored in Assets/Blender
2. The game object has an AlembicStreamPlayer and PlayableDirector component on it

Comment: How is the file referenced from within unity?

Comment: Correct, all files under Assets are not in existance in the build, with a couple of exceptions, a) things you mark as streamed assets, plugins, and Resources everything else is either compiled up or just not available..  if you look in your build area you will see none of your asset paths exist

Comment: How do I fix the reference to the alembic file when building out the game then? Is there a way to manually override it?

Comment: is there a reason why you place it in `StreamingAssets`? as the name suggests these are supposed to be streamed -> fileIO loaded on runtime .. why not simply place it under the normal assets and reference it directly?

Comment: @derHugo It gets automatically placed in StreamingAssets when I build the game. In my project it's in a folder Assets/Blender. Should it be placed somewhere else?